# как сделать проверку ip за сегодня в бд?

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю небольшой фильтр. Нужна проверка ip по бд, за сегодняшний день. То есть, если сегодня юзер проголосовал - то он голосовать сегодня за определенный материал не может. Что получилось:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$time = date("Y-m-d");

$ipcheck = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from rate WHERE id = '$id' AND from = '$ip' "));

if (date("Y-m-d",strtotime($ipcheck['date'])) == $time) {
    $text = "Вы уже голосовали сегодня за данный материал!";
}

else     { ...
```

Ошибка в том, что вылазит в запросе, мол не хватает чего-то:
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Так же, выполняется сам скрипт, то есть то, что после else.

Тип поля date в бд timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
То есть записи в ним вида 2012-04-27 16:24:05

Comment: не советаою ставить запрет на основе IP) под одни IP может сидеть более 1000 человек

Comment: @Ale_x, и один человек под 1000 IP)))

Comment: и так тоже моно))))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвратительная привычка давать полям названия, которые являются служебными. 
Переименуйте поле **from**. Если уж надо сделать запрос именно с этим названием, то делайте так:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `rate` WHERE `id` = '$id' AND `from` = '$ip' ")
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло ;)
Про это не знал, теперь учту)